# BIRT - check if parameter exists in master page header section.

Tags: birt

i am using birt reports version 2.5.0
my report uses a input parameter called reportParam.
my report uses a global master page where in its header section i want to add some text depends on the value of the reportParam parameter.
there is no problem when i use the code:

```
var addedString = "";
if( params["reportParam"].value == 1){
    addedString ="some Added string";
}
```

my problem is that since my master page is global and defined as a shared resource, it might be used by reports that does not have the  `params["reportParam"]` and for those reports an exception will get thrown and the report wont be generated.
i need a way to check if the `params["reportParam"]` exists.

i have seen this solution to the problem:

```
var addedString = "";
var params = reportContext.getDesignHandle().getAllParameters();
//traverse that list
for(var i=0; i<params.size(); i++) {
  var sParClass = params.get( i ).getClass().toString();
  //we need to check if it is a real parameter and not a parameter group
  if( sParClass == "class org.eclipse.birt.report.model.api.ScalarParameterHandle" ) {
    //do checks here...just a demo how to get name and value
    var parameterName = params.get( i ).getFullName();
    if( parameterName == "ResolutionPRM" ){
        if( params["reportParam"].value == 1 ){
        addedString ="some Added string";
        }
    }   
  }
}
```

but this sulotion doesnt seems to work on the master page header section since reportContext is not known (the master page section is a regular expression builder and not a script section where reportContext is recognized).
any idea how can i achive my goal in the master page ?
thanks

Answer (score 2):

sorry, but the answer is simpler that i imagined:
var addedString = "";

```
try
{
  if( params["reportParam"].value == 1){
      addedString ="some Added string";
  }
}
catch(err)
{
}
```

will do the trick. if the report does not have `params["reportParam"]` an exception will be thrown and catch in the catch section of the code and,... well all will continue as if nothing had happened.

Comment: You should accept your answer so the question will not show up as unanswered.